# How can empty JavaScript function actually do something?

Tags: javascript

While trying to understand how a web server worked, I came accross this:

```
//myfile.js
function donothing(){};

//myfile.html
javascript:donothing(open('http://www.acme.com/whatever.jpg','','left=100, right=0, top=100, scrollbars=no, status=no, titlebar=no, resizable=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, width=255, height=255'))
```

I'm no JavaScript expert, so I don't get how an empty function can be made to work. Does someone know?

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a homemade `void` substitute to avoid having the expression return a value.

`window.open` will return a reference to the opened window, and this can have unexpected results.

For instance, try pasting `javascript:a=1` into the address field - this will result in a blank screen with the number 1 in it as the browser will by default try to use the result of any expression run as the new document.

To avoid this you use `javascript:void(a=1)` as void will not return anything, and so the result isn't used as the new document.

Using `donothing(foo=bar)` or the equivalent `Function.prototype(foo=bar)` is not needed as the built-in `void` does the exact same.

But mind, the use of void is **only** needed when copying text into the address field, its not necessary when you use the pseudo protocol `javscript:` in links (which you should never do anyway).

Answer (score 3):

The one that does the work is `open(...)`. The operands are evaluated first before the function is called (and Javascript doesn't care about the number of operands to the function).

Answer (score 2):

The `donothing` function is passed a parameter that it ignores. It is the parameter itself that does the work, however.

Comment: Actually, in order to pass the parameter to donothing, it is first executed. The RESULT (return value) from the function (in this case open) is then passed to donothing.

Answer (score 1):

the call to `donothing` is just acting as a shroud. The open function is being called before donothing.

Apparently whomever wrote it felt the naked javascript: call was vulnerable. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Well, although it is difficult to understand the point of `donothing` without seeing the rest of the code... the open function will be evaluated anyway.
So effectively what is happening is that the `open` function is being called.

Why they're using `donothing` to do it is difficult to say without other info :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. The donothing() is located in a .js file, and is used in hyperlinks such as: <a href="javascript:donothing(open('http://www.acme.com/whatever.jpg','','left=100, right=0, top=100, scrollbars=no, status=no, titlebar=no, resizable=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, width=242, height=325'))"><img src='http://www.acme.com/whatever.jpg'>Click me</a>

Comment: What's even weirder, is that the Fiddler proxy doesn't display anything when I click on this type of hyperlink :-/

Comment: Its not strange if the image is served from the cache. Mind selecting one of the answers as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

> But mind, the use of void is only needed when copying text into the address field, its not necessary when you use the pseudo protocol javscript: in links (which you should never do anyway).

Not 100% true. If you write, in html, `<a href="javascript:1+2;">clickme</a>`, many browsers will still give you an empty screen with the return value that evaluates to true in Javascript. That's the precise reason to use the void operator in `<a>` tags also when you, for example, auto-generate tags in a template language.